# error class not catching thrown errors

Tags: php, oop, exception, error-handling

I have an exception class that looks like this

```
<?php
class Errors{
    public function displayError(Exception $e){
        $trace = $e->getTrace();
            if($trace[0]['class'] != ""){
            $class = $trace[0]['class'];
            $method = $trace[0]['function'];
            $file = $trace[0]['file'];
            $line = $trace[0]['line'];
            $error_message = $e->getMessage().
            "<br /> Class/Method : ".$class." <==> ".$method.
            "<br /> File : ".$file.
            "<br /> Line : ".$line;
        }
     return $error_message;
    }
  }
 ?>
```

This works fine for many errors that are thrown due do typos/column count not matching value count, but when I throw an exception from the code myself, I get an error. For example

```
  try{
            $stmt = $db->dbh->prepare("SELECT user FROM reset ");
            $stmt->execute();
            if ($stmt->rowCount() < 1){
                throw new Exception('The Link expired, request a new one');
              } else {
              throw new Exception('The Link is invalid, please request a new one');
            }
          }
            catch (PDOException $e) {
    $error = new Errors();
    echo "<b>".$error->displayError($e)."</b>";
}
```

I get `Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'The Link is invalid, please request a new one'` error when I run the code. If I remove that line, and induce an error by spelling `SELECT` as `SLECT`, the error class works fine.

How can I make in such a way that the error class will catch all types of errors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `NOT all exceptions are PDOExceptions`.You code cacthes only `PDOException` which means `new Exception` won't be catched. Try :

```
try
{
     $stmt = $db->dbh->prepare("SELECT user FROM reset ");
     ...
}
catch (PDOException $e) 
{
    $error = new Errors();
    echo "<b>".$error->displayError($e)."</b>";
}
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    $error = new Errors();
    echo "<b>".$error->displayError($e)."</b>";
}
```

The reason why your code works when you spell `SELECT` as `SLECT` is because you triggered a `PDOException` instead of  a `new Exception`.